# how to map ubuntu shared folder in windows 7?

Tags: file, ubuntu, vmware, sharing, server

My host OS is *Windows 7* and I have an *Ubuntu 14.04* install as guest OS. I would like to know how can I share particular folders from *Ubuntu* and map them as a drive in *Windows 7*.

Answer (score 3):

To share host file with guest vm in vmware workstation you can use VM->settings->options->shared folders. It's quite easy to use.

If you want to create a share directory on guest Ubuntu system and map it as a network driver on windows system. You may need to create a samba share and then map it in windows.
on Utunbu:

- $sudo apt-get install samba
- $smbpasswd -a geek
- $mkdir ~/Desktop/Share
- $sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

> ```
> [<folder_name>]
> path = /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
> available = yes
> valid users = <user_name>
> read only = no
> browsable = yes
> public = yes
> writable = yes</li>
> ```
>
> $sudo service smbd restart
>
> On windows map the \UtuntuIP-ADDRESS\SHARE-NAME to a network driver.

Comment: tried and getting some error like the folder is not valid , try with another folder. is there something to do with IP or network? as i cannot see ubuntu system in my windows network. I have a wifi set up on my desktop, my ip gets changed very often and ubuntu has static ip

Comment: Are you install Ubuntu in a virtual machine?  And what's the network setting for the VM?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy and basically you need to configure two parts: 1. setup a shared folder on Ubuntu; 2. setup the network disk mapping on windows to the shared folder.

Below shows the setup steps. ([This link contains a great-detailed tutorial about the whole process.](http://stopswimming.com/remotely-access-ubuntu-shared-folder-network-disk-windows-10/) If you get any trouble, I recommend to go to [this link and follow the details](http://stopswimming.com/remotely-access-ubuntu-shared-folder-network-disk-windows-10/).)

**On ubuntu**, let us use samba to build a shared folder:

1. you need to install samba from terminal:

   sudo apt-get install samba
2. add your current ubuntu account to samba (suppose your ubuntu account is sharetest):

   sudo smbpasswd -a sharetest

Then it reqires you to setup the password of your account in samba:
[image]

3. create your folder to be shared, for example, the folder you share has name shared_folder,

   mkdir /home/sharetest/shared_folder
4. configure samba to recognize your shared_folder and grant corresponding read, write and browsing configurations, by editing file smb.conf using vi editor

   sudo vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

Go to the end of smb.conf and add the following content (Find out how to use vi editor by yourself if you are not familiar with it.):

[image]

The above figure shows the configuration of this specific example, you need to customize your configurations (settings enclosed by <> below) accordingly.

```
[<your_shared_folder_name>]
path = <your_shared_folder_path>
available = yes
valid users = <your_account_name>
read only = no
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

5. restart the samba service

   sudo service smbd restart

**On Windows**:

1. Go to your windows file explore and right click on **This PC** and you can see the dropdown menu. Left click on **Map network drive ...**.
2. Choose your Drive symbol (say we use Y:). And configure the Folder path of your shared folder in this format:

   \\your_ubuntu_ip\your_shared_folder_name

All done.

Comment: Can see the folder on windows, but cannot access.  What's the windows user supposed to be? Same username?

Answer (score -1):

If you are working on virtual machine environment, you should be using 'Shared Folders' between your host OS and guest OS(running in vm).